# Cmd process run browserify from C# desktop not working

Tags: c#, watchify

In my package.json

```js
"gui-app": "watchify ./gui/app.js -p [esmify --noImplicitAny] -o ./public/gui.build.js",
```

I use cmd terminal C# project from:

Author: Curt C.
Project File: "Solving Problems of Monitoring Standard Output and Error Streams Of A Running Process" for http://www.codeproject.com

It is C# PROCESS helper project.

```
txtBxStdin.Text = @"npm run gui-editor-watch";
btnSendStdinToProcess.PerformClick();
```

This code works fine but only `watchify` not effect, no error.

Must be something around process handling...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a chromiumWebBrowser cache.

I fixed with call:

```cs
 try {
  using (var devToolsClient = chromiumWebBrowser1.GetDevToolsClient()) {
     var response = await devToolsClient.Network.ClearBrowserCacheAsync();
     chromiumWebBrowser1.LoadUrl(URLTEXT.Text);
  }
 } catch (Exception err) {
  MessageBox.Show("ERROR IN CLEAR CACHE [chromiumWebBrowser1]", err.ToString());
  }
```